# How to cite an anonymous quote from a paper

Tags: citation-style

I have a quote from an anonymous participant of a study reported in a paper, say by John Smith in 2021. Let's say in the paper it said:

> One participant commented:
>
> *It's really surprising that the widgets don't do foo. Without foo, the widgets may as well not even exist*.

How should the quote be cited in APA style? I want to particularly avoid making it look like Smith wrote the bit about widgets, and instead make it clear it's a quote from a participant.

Comment: The source is the paper your cite. Then you should format your writing so that it is evident that you quote a statement provided by the cited reference. there is no obvious way to directly quote a quote in a paper since you do not know the actual source. Only the quoted paper knows the source.

Comment: *As a participant noted in Smith (2021), "'It's really surprising ...'"

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- Ah the extra single quotes, didn't think of that! Is this explicit in APA? (and... maybe write this as an answer?)

Comment: @MichalCharemza No, that's just how you quote quotes in American English.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him-  Are you sure? It looks weird to me. Obviously you use nested quotes when necessary, but in all the examples I have seen, there are at least a few words that are inside the outer quotes but not inside the inner quotes. If there are no words like that, I think a single level of quotes is better.

Comment: @gib I confess I'm not positive, it's been a while since I was a copy editor, however it does strike me  as slightly inaccurate to *not* use them since it could imply it was a paraphrase or something. I did check APA somewhat thoroughly but couldn't find an answer, and a brief Google of AP Style (which I used when I was a copy editor) wasn't super helpful either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just cite Smith and write a few words to make it clear it's a quote from a participant in his study. The exact choice of words will depend on what exactly you are saying.